# Inventory View inventory_stock_1 causing database locks

Tags: database, inventory, multi-source-inventory

After moving databases we are getting spikes in our database from PDP pages with the following query, and it ends up taking a full minute to query.

```
SELECT `inventory_stock_1`.`quantity`, `inventory_stock_1`.`is_salable` FROM `inventory_stock_1` WHERE (sku = 'SKU-123')
```

When we drop the view, the site works, but we start getting exceptions

```
[2020-11-18 19:19:51] report.CRITICAL: Could not receive Stock Item data {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Could not receive Stock Item data at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-indexer/Model/ResourceModel/GetStockItemData.php:68, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42):
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DATABASE.inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `inventory_stock_1`.`quantity`, `inventory_stock_1`.`is_salable` FROM `inventory_stock_1` WHERE (sku = 'sku-123') at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DATABASE.inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

1. What is the purpose of this view? It was added in Mutli Warehouse module but basically seems like its just the data from cataloginventory_stock_status with a sku attached.
2. Why would this simple view create locks?

Answer (score 0):

So after multiple attempts to fix, we've discovered a solution that seems to work. Essentially removing DISTINCT from the query creating the view.

https://github.com/magento/inventory/pull/1950

> According to my investigation magento 2.3.1 is still querying view
> inventory_stock_1 by sku. The problem is that the view cannot use sku
> index, as it is using temporary algorithm because of the select
> distinct.
>
> I have tried to replace the inventory_stock_1 view to the following :
>
> ```
> CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW inventory_stock_1
> AS select legacy_stock_status.product_id AS
> product_id,legacy_stock_status.website_id AS
> website_id,legacy_stock_status.stock_id AS
> stock_id,legacy_stock_status.qty AS
> quantity,legacy_stock_status.stock_status AS is_salable,product.sku AS
> sku from (cataloginventory_stock_status legacy_stock_status join
> catalog_product_entity product on((legacy_stock_status.product_id =
> product.entity_id)));
> ```
>
> If somebody is using one website with one
> stock, this query would return distinct results anyway, so this may be
> a workaround to this performance problem in such case.